# Copy-Item not including subfolder files of source directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy-item, file-move

I have a script which moves files with a specific extension from a source directory to a destination directory.

My source directory looks like:

**FILESFOLDER**

- File1.td
- File2.td

  **SUBFOLDER**

  - File3.td
  - File4.td

My script is short and looks like:

```
if(!(Test-Path $SourceDirPath) -or !(Test-Path $DestinationDirPath))
{
    Write-Host "The source- or destination path is incorrect, please check "
    break
}else
{
    Write-Host "Success"
    Copy-Item -path $SourceDirPath -Filter "*$extension" -Destination $DestinationDirPath -Recurse
}
```

**I have to mention** that the `$SourceDirPath` comes from a config file and only works if I declare it as `C:\FILESFOLDER\*`

The script works but doesn't copy the files from the subfolder to destination. The destination only has File1 and File2.

What's wrong with my Copy-Item command?

Comment: Do you want to copy the files in the subfolders with the subfolders themselves? Or you only want the files?

Comment: I want to have the exact same structure in the destination so with the subfolders and the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this will compare the directory source versus the destination and then copy over the content. Ignore my funky variables, I've amended them below on a edit

```
 #Release folder
    $Source =  ""
    #Local folder
    $Destination = ""

    #Find all the objects in the release
    get-childitem $Source -Recurse | foreach {

    $SrcFile = $_.FullName
    $SrcHash = Get-FileHash -Path $SrcFile -Algorithm MD5 # Obtain hash

    $DestFile = $_.Fullname -replace [RegEx]::escape($Source),$Destination #Escape the hash
    Write-Host "comparing $SrcFile to $DestFile" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    if (Test-Path $DestFile) 
    {
    #Check the hash sum of the file copied
    $DestHash = Get-FileHash -Path $DestFile -Algorithm MD5

    #compare them up
    if ($SrcHash.hash -ne $DestHash.hash) {
        Write-Warning "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files don't match!"

        Write-Warning "Copying $SrcFile to $DestFile " 

        Copy-Item $SrcFile -Destination $DestFile -Force
    } 
    else {
        Write-Host "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files Match" -ForegroundColor 
Green

    }
        } 
    else {
        Write-host "$SrcFile is missing! Copying in" -ForegroundColor Red
        Copy-Item $SrcFile -Destination $DestFile -Force

         }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, you just added the `-Force` and changed the position of the switches? I still only have 2 files in the destination folder

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't work. It says `Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.``

Comment: It's because I missed a variable off my copy and paste. I've got to run in a minute but I've added a script above I wrote that does a binary comparison on objects and then recuse copies. This will do what you want, but will also do a binary comparison and report color coded references to the Ps. It's a very long winded way of doing what you want but will do it !

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working but I guess your answer doesn't overwrite if there are already files inside?

Comment: It does, if they are different. Where in your case this would be the only reason you would be updating (if you get my drift) - The MD5 algorithm is great for that as it checks the actually file hash, as well as the contents. It's a comprehensive check rather than some "oh it's the same date" and move on.

Comment: I just realised it indeed does if there are differences between the file. Thanks again for this great piece of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141647/discussion-between-kahn-kah-and-richard-dakin).

Answer (score 4):

**The `-Recurse` switch has no effect in your case**, because it's only applied to the items matched by the combination of `$SourceDirPath`, which uses a trailing `\*` to match the items *in* the source directory, and `-Filter`, which in your case are only the `*.td` files located *directly* in your source directory.

**Omitting the trailing `\*`** to target the directory itself (e.g., `C:\FOLDER` rather than `C:\FOLDER\*`), solves that problem *in principle*, but, [due to an annoying quirk](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2934) **only works as intended if the destination directory does *not* exist yet.**
If it does exist, the items are placed in a *subdirectory* of the destination directory, named for the *source* directory.

**If there's nothing in the existing destination directory to preserve** before copying (and no special attributes of directory itself need preserving, you can **work around the problem by *deleting* the preexisting destination directory beforehand**.

```
if(!(Test-Path $SourceDirPath) -or !(Test-Path $DestinationDirPath))
{
    Write-Host "The source or destination path is incorrect, please check "
    break
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Success"

    # Delete the preexisting destination directory,
    # which is required for the Copy-Item command to work as intended.
    # BE SURE THAT IT IS OK TO DO THIS.
    Remove-Item $DestinationDirPath -Recurse

    # Note: $SourceDirPath must NOT end in \*  
    Copy-Item -Recurse -LiteralPath $SourceDirPath -Filter "*$extension" -Destination $DestinationDirPath
}
```

If you do need to preserve existing `$DestinationDirPath` content or attributes (ACLs, ...), more work is needed.

Comment: It didn't work sadly, it also removes my whole destination folder?

Comment: @KahnKah: As stated (let me know if I can make that clearer in the answer): **The workaround _requires_ that the destination folder be _removed first_** (I know that's annoying - `Copy-Item` is broken in many ways). Aside from that, however, it should work. So: Are you saying it doesn't work, or are you saying that you must preserve content in the existing destination directory?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet with the `-recurse` parameter to retrieve all files based on your filter condition. Then you can pipe the result to the `Copy-Item` cmdlet and only have to specify a destination.

Comment: Would that also let me have the exact same structure both in the source as the destination directory?

Comment: You have to take care about that yourself. You may consider using Robocopy for that.

Comment: Not quite, this is possible, 
Do you want to compare before copy or just copy everything regardless of presence at the destination?

Comment: I want to copy regardless, @Richard, would you tell me that `Get-ChildItem`wouldn't work in this case?

Comment: Martin it doesn't work I tried `Get-ChildItem  -Path $SourceDirPath -Filter "*$extension"  -Recurse |Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationDirPath` and it just retrieves the files, not the structure with the subfolder

Comment: Yes? You mentioned Robocopy but I can't use any external stuff. PS only

Comment: I have told you that you have to take care about the structure yourself. Also, robocopy comes with windows, its not an external tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$source =  "C:\Folder1"

$destination = "C:\Folder2"

$allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter "*$extension"
foreach ($file in $allfiles){
    if (test-path ($file.FullName.replace($source,$destination))) {
    Write-Output "Seccess"
    Copy-Item -path $file.FullName -Destination ($file.FullName.replace($source,$destination))
    }
    else {
    Write-Output "The source- or destination path is incorrect, please check "
    break
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get my script to work if my source doesn't have `\*`